# How to expand Swift module functionality? How to apply custom font in Cairo?

Tags: swift, module, cairo, vapor

My Swift Vapor backend code uses this `Graphics` module: https://github.com/fwcd/swift-graphics

`Graphics` uses `Cairo` module: https://github.com/fwcd/swift-cairo.git

`Graphics` module has the `CairoGraphics` class.

When it is initalized:

```swift
import Cairo
import Utils

public class CairoGraphics: Graphics {
    private let context: Cairo.Context // <-- this is private, can not access from outer code
    private let image: Image

    deinit {
        flush()
    }

    public init(fromImage image: Image) {
        context = Cairo.Context(surface: image.surface) // <-- created here
        self.image = image
    }
```

it creates a `Cairo.Context` object.

`Cairo.Context` has a method, I would call from my code, to set custom font for rendering.

```swift
public func setFont(face: (family: String, slant: Cairo.FontSlant, weight: Cairo.FontWeight))
```

1. How can I call this method from the outer code? `CairoGraphics` does not have a public property for it, only private, I highlighted above.

I know this is a naive question, but:

2. Can I add a public method to `CairoGraphics`? Or there is a `CairoGraphics`'s binary code, and this swift file is only an 'interface', or 'agreement'? If I add a new method it will not trigger anything as the 'binary' does not have corresponding logic?

---

I tried to add an extension, but the this error:

> 'context' is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level

```swift
extension CairoGraphics {
    func getContext() -> Cairo.Context {
        return context
    }
}
```

---

Or shall I pull, fork, push to GitHub, do slight changes, and use my own version?

Comment: Can you access the Cairo functions directly as described on this page: https://www.cairographics.org/manual/cairo-text.html ? If not, the limitations given may be why you can't do much from this wrapper.